# Can't set label background nor callouts color to the the variable @symbol_color

Tags: labeling, color, qgis-variable, callout, data-defined-override

Working with QGIS 3.22.8 you can set a data defined override for label color to match that of the associated feature using the variable @symbol_color, but it does not work for label background fill/outline color nor for callout lines color no matter what I do.
Is this a known issue or is there anything I'm doing wrong?

To give some more details. I'm styling my point layer using rule based symbology and rule based labels. I set the @symbol_color variable for:

- Label text color **- it works!**
- Label background (rectangle shaped) outline color **- ignores data defined override**
- Label callouts line color **- ignores data defined override**

Comment: This seems to work as expected on recent QGIS versions (tested on 3.32).