# Expression to get symbol color from categorized layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, expression, color

I want to get the color of a categorized symbol to be used as background color of a textframe in the printcomposer.  The color has to change automaticly when the feature-name changes.

[image]

Is there an expression in QGIS that refers to the symbolcolor of a layer?  And how would the expression look like to  get the specific color of a symbol in the layer legend?

I'm using QGIS 3.22.5

Comment: Like... `@symbol_color`?

Comment: @Erik: yes, something like that.  But how do you parse it into an expression to get the specific color of the layer legend?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot ? It's unclear.

Comment: Fyi if your symbol has multiple elements to it (e.g. dashed line over a solid line etc) `@symbol_color` will always take the bottom most element in the list of symbols.

Comment: Also it seem that @symbol_color didn't work in all context (see this for exemple : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440200/cant-set-label-background-nor-callouts-color-to-the-the-variable-symbol-color)

Comment: @J.R is this a bug?  Or a missing feature in QGIS?

Comment: @PieterB not sure if this is a bug, a missing feature or some QGIS limitation to get the color in some context...

Comment: @etrimaille I added a screenshot to my question